# input.scrollLeft behaves unexpectedly in Chome & Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

We are trying to build an input-field with syntax highlighting where the input is hidden but an overlaying div with the text / value is shown. This works perfectly so far. We've already tried the contenteditable approach mentioned [here](https://codepen.io/brianmearns/pen/YVjZWw), but it ran into various issues (e.g. handling cursor position and IE 11) that seem solvable but rather messy.

Since we have to handle the overflow (and a htmlInput is scrolling automatically), we're trying to set the scrollLeft of the overlay-container the same as the scrollLeft of the input to have them perfectly matched.

However, we're experiencing various inconsistencies between browsers on how the scrollLeft is applied.

Curiously enough, IE11 works flawlessly. In Firefox (68.0.2), the overlay is consistently off by about a single character, where as in Chrome (76.0.3809.100) the difference between the offsets grows larger the more you type. See see the example code below or this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/oliver-barwig/pen/XWrRNJr) for a demonstration of the Firefox and Chrome issues. As soon as the input begins to overflow, the two fields will become misaligned to various degrees.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var container = document.getElementById('overlay');

input.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    container.innerHTML = event.target.value;
    container.scrollLeft = input.scrollLeft;
  })
});
```

```css
#input {
  font: 400 1rem sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

#overlay {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font: 400 1rem sans-serif;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

How does the `scrollLeft` behaviour differ between browsers, and how can we ensure consistency between input and overlay position?

**Update**

The problem only seems to happen in Chrome on Windows10. 
We used `textarea` (styled like an `input`) instead of `input` and now it works perfectly.

Comment: Input does not have scrollLeft property, as it is not scrollable. I am not sure how you've got to move the viewport at all...

Comment: Input is an element, and all [elements have the scrollLeft property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft), so I don't see why input should not have one

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox, you apparently will need to wait more than *0ms*. A *50ms* delay seems to work fine for me.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var container = document.getElementById('overlay');

input.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    container.innerHTML = event.target.value;
    container.scrollLeft = input.scrollLeft;
  }, 50)
});
```

```css
#input {
  font: 400 1rem sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

#overlay {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font: 400 1rem sans-serif;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

For Chrome, I couldn't reproduce on v76 on macOS, so I can't be sure if the delay trick is enough there too.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The 50ms delay indeed seems to solve the issue for Firefox. As for Chrome, the issue seems to happen on Windows (Windows 10, to be exact) systems only, while it's working fine on macOS (at least 10.14.5, as far as we can tell).

Comment: For Chrome I unfortunately can't verify, but are you sure the same font is used for both elements? Also double check every property related to the text rendering, e.g [kerning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-kerning), and all that are listed [as related](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-kerning#See_also)

Comment: Unfortunately none of the css options made any difference. It's also quite clear in chrome the two fields match exactly until any scroll happens, so it's probably nothing along those lines. In the end, we decided to go with a `textarea` instead of an `input`-field, and now our solution works flawlessly. Thanks for your help anyway.